# What's the difference between the usage of these terms: 信念　信用　信頼?

Tags: words

I understand these words roughly translate to "trust" or "reliance" but I don't understand the nuance between these words.

Answer (score 3):

信念 seems to be about a somewhat abstract belief or faith in something, or for example trusting your own convictions.

信用 and 信頼 seem to be mostly about interpersonal trust or reliance. The difference, according to [a page I found](https://biz.trans-suite.jp/4844) is as follows:

信用=信じて用いる、信じて受け入れる

I.e. to believe and accept, for example accord trust based on previous experience and results (of dealing with this person). 信用 is something you can gain (得る), lose (失う), and regain (取り戻す). This is also why one of the possible translations of it is “credit” or “confidence” which can be gained or lost.

信頼=信じて、頼りにする

I.e. believe and rely on (someone), or trust (someone) to be reliable. You can betray (裏切る) this trust. Another possible translation is “rely on”.

If you believe in someone enough that you know you can rely on them and vice versa, you can be said to be in 信頼関係 (mutual trust relationship, or *fiduciary* in financial terms).

Overall, it seems 信用 is about trust based on somewhat objective experience or evaluation while 信頼 can be somewhat subjective and based on “gut feeling”.